# How to block packets using snort?

Tags: network-programming, packet, packet-sniffers, snort

I know detection of packets using snort and wireshark.
Now my question is how to block this detected packet using snort. And give me idea about how to create custom rules snort?

I am in great trouble Plz help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

at running time you can use snort-inline.conf to block the malicious packets